# XSLT Transversing and selection

Tags: xslt

I am very new to xslt and need some assistance with a particular piece of code
I have an XML file:
`

```
<in:inputs xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
<!-- Function Call Result (0 ms), XPath /in:inputs/in:result[@name='SitemapXml']/Page-->
<in:result name="SitemapXml">
    <Page MenuTitle="Frontpage" UrlTitle="Home"  FolderPath="/Home" Depth="1"  xmlns="">
        <Page Depth="2" />
        <Page MenuTitle="Treadmills Reviews" UrlTitle="Treadmills-Reviews" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Treadmills-Reviews" Depth="2" isopen="true" iscurrent="true"  >
            <Page MenuTitle="Sole Fitness" UrlTitle="Sole-Fitness" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Treadmills-Reviews/Sole-Fitness" Depth="3">
                <Page MenuTitle="F-Series" UrlTitle="F-Series" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Treadmills-Reviews/Sole-Fitness/F-Series" Depth="4">
                    <Page MenuTitle="F63" UrlTitle="F63" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Treadmills-Reviews/Sole-Fitness/F-Series/F63" Depth="5" />
                </Page>
            </Page>
            <Page MenuTitle="Nordic Track" UrlTitle="Nordic-Track" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Treadmills-Reviews/Nordic-Track" Depth="3"/>
        </Page>
        <Page MenuTitle="Our Top Picks" UrlTitle="Our-Top-Picks" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Our-Top-Picks" Depth="2"/>
        <Page MenuTitle="Forums" UrlTitle="Forums" Description=""  FolderPath="/Home/Forums" Depth="2"/>
    </Page>
</in:result>
```

`

I am trying to transverse the nodes with xslt and then print out the value of the "MenuTitle" of the node that "iscurrent='true'".  There could be any number of levels of "Page" nodes as well as the iscurrent attribute will be in which ever page is currently open.

My xslt file is as follows 
    `

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
<span>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="HeaderName" select="."/>
</span>

  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="HeaderName" match="*">
<xsl:if test="@iscurrent='true'">
    <xsl:value-of  select="@MenuTilte" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

What am I doing wrong if not everything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This transform :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="in:result">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Page[@iscurrent = 'true']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Page">

<xsl:message terminate="no">
  <xsl:value-of select="@MenuTitle"/>
</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input .xml file which I assume has some formatting mistakes, i.e. the comment is not correct as it comment the whole .xml out and there are two root element( I commended out the first one)

Will output message :

```
[xslt] Treadmills Reviews
```

Of course in your case you will have to use the value of the attribute or in any case do something which suits your needs.

Regarding your xslt. Make sure you use the correct namespace and that you select correct nodes in your apply templates element.

The above xsl is for testing purposes only. Change the output to html and remove the message element. Youy will end up in something like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="in:result">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <span>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Page[@iscurrent = 'true']"/>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Page">

  <xsl:value-of select="@MenuTitle"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I guess I did copy the xml here incorrectly as the comment was messed up.  It is correct in my working copy.  Will the transform that you showed, recursively check all the Page nodes for the attribute "iscurrent". This is import because it might not always be in the Page node with the MenuTitle="Treadmill Reviews"

Comment: Line : //Page[@iscurrent = 'true']"/> selects all Pages elements which are descendants of the root element with attribute iscurrent = true.

Comment: I appreciate the time you are taking to look over this.  Your solution makes sense to me and yet I still can't get it to work when I run my xml.  I just get a blank screen. I must be missing something. I basically copied your code directly into my xsl file and even commented out the <in:inputs> element, but still am not able to get it to work.  I am pretty sure that my namespaces are correct.                                                                                                                          Other than the code is the code you supplied above.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you remove the <message/> element? Simply comment out the message element and use the value. Youy .html should then work. Message only outputs to std out of your xslt processor. See edited answer. Also try to understand what is going on here and avoid simply pasting it - play with the code a little bit :)

Comment: There we go I got it working properly thanks to all of your input.  Appreciated greatly thanks.

Comment: @dherrin79 Np we are here to help :D